# I try to open a php file in my browser localhost but everytime when i double click it it makes me save it

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

It makes me save the file, dont know why and i cant see how it looks in browser.

I have already installed LAMP and i have saved the file in var/www/html as index.php with a `<?php echo 'hello'; ?>` in it, but when i save it and try to open it in my broswer it makes me save the file instead of seeing it in the browser

Answer (score 0):

Opening the file directly in the browser won't work as the browser cannot execute the PHP code, you are bypassing the LAMP stack this way.

Instead you'll want to access the LAMP stack by browsing to http://localhost